# I want to present the username from database JAVA Jframe

Tags: java, sqlite, swing, jframe, guice

I have two `JFrame` windows one for the login and the second for the welcome. Now I want to present the `Firstname` and the `Lastname` of the connected user near to the hello in the welcome screen.

I tried many things but none of them worked so I'm asking for you help. I just started to learn GUI:

[image: Login Greeting]
[image: Welcome Greeting]

The login code:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Login {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel MainLogo;
    String  Firstname=null; 
    String  Lastname=null;


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Login window = new Login();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    Connection connected = null;
    private JTextField UsernameFiled;
    private JPasswordField passwordField;

    public Login() {
        initialize();

        connected = DBConnection.DBconnector();

    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 560, 256);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("UserName: ");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(160, 11, 140, 50);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

        JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("PassWord: ");
        lblPassword.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
        lblPassword.setBounds(160, 72, 140, 40);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblPassword);

        JButton Loginbtn = new JButton("Login");
        Loginbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                try {


                    String query = "Select * from Users where nickname=? and password=?";
                    PreparedStatement pst = connected.prepareStatement(query);
                    pst.setString(1, UsernameFiled.getText());
                    pst.setString(2, passwordField.getText());

                    ResultSet res = pst.executeQuery();
                    Firstname = res.getString("Firstname");
                    Lastname = res.getString("Lastname");
                    int c=0;

                    while(res.next()) {
                        c++;
                    }

                    if(c == 0) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You didnt put any username or password!");
                    }
                    else if(c == 1) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello to you, " + Firstname +" "+ Lastname);
                        frame.dispose();
                        UserPage UserFrame = new UserPage();
                        UserFrame.setVisible(true);

                    }else if( c > 1) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Duplicate Username and Password");
                    }else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username and Password are inncorect...Try agian!");
                    }

                    pst.close();
                    res.close();

                }catch(Exception LoginError) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, LoginError);

                }




            }
        });

        Loginbtn.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
        Loginbtn.setBounds(160, 148, 186, 40);
        frame.getContentPane().add(Loginbtn);

        UsernameFiled = new JTextField();
        UsernameFiled.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        UsernameFiled.setBounds(310, 28, 186, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(UsernameFiled);
        UsernameFiled.setColumns(10);

        passwordField = new JPasswordField();
        passwordField.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        passwordField.setBounds(310, 84, 186, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(passwordField);

        MainLogo = new JLabel("");
        Image imgs = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/login.png")).getImage();
        MainLogo.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imgs));
        MainLogo.setBounds(10, 11, 128, 128);
        frame.getContentPane().add(MainLogo);
    }
}
```

The Welcome Code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class UserPage extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UserPage frame = new UserPage();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */

    Connection connected=null;
    private JTable table;

    public UserPage() {
        connected=DBConnection.DBPreconnector();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 576, 410);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JButton bntLoadData = new JButton("Show Users Data");
        bntLoadData.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                try {

                    String query = "Select ID,Age,Password,Firstname,Lastname from users";
                    PreparedStatement pst = connected.prepareStatement(query);

                    ResultSet res = pst.executeQuery();
                    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(res));


                } catch (Exception Error) {

                    Error.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Hello,  "  + "The Username name");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 11, 280, 19);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

        bntLoadData.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
        bntLoadData.setBounds(162, 102, 238, 23);
        contentPane.add(bntLoadData);

        table = new JTable();
        table.setBounds(28, 136, 508, 221);
        contentPane.add(table);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 4) *"none of them worked"* I was about to ask 'how did they fail?' and then noticed..

Comment: .. `catch(Exception LoginError) { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, LoginError); }`. That's not going to provide useful information. Change it to `catch(Exception LoginError) { LoginError.printStackTrace(); JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, LoginError); }` then if you cannot understand the stack trace, copy/paste it as an [edit] to the question. 5) *"I just started to learn GUI:"* So the SQL works from the command line? I suspect this is trying too much at once.

Comment: Setting bounds manually is not a good practice. This is what layout managers are for. See [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you does not seem to load the username or password of the logged in user at the welcome frame. Either you will have to pass that from the login frame or you will have to re-query the database and get firstname and lastname.

I suggest, simply pass the firstname and lastname from welcome screen via constructor.

In successful login, simply pass the name in the constructor: Login code addition:

```
                } else if(c == 1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello to you, " + Firstname +" "+ Lastname);
                    frame.dispose();
                    UserPage UserFrame = new UserPage( Firstname, Lastname );
                    UserFrame.setVisible(true);
                }
```

In the welcome frame, add a constructor to handle this:

```
public UserPage(String loggedInFirstName, String loggedInLastName){
   // your remaining code
   JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Hello,  "  + loggedInFirstName + " " + loggedInLastName );
   // your remaining code.
}
```

A approach like this might work for your case and don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if this works for you

Comment: Hey your solution worked but i have question for you when I added the code for the constructor in the welcome page other line yell about me and enforce me to add some nulls i side can you explain me why?
this is the code line:

`public static void main(String[] args) {
  EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    try {
     UserPage frame = new UserPage(null, null);
     frame.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  });
 }`
this is the spesific line

`UserPage frame = new UserPage(null, null);`

Comment: Yeah, that is because now you don't have a no-argument constructor defined in the code. Only constructor you have is the constructor that expects two String arguments. So either you have to pass null like above or, define another constructor with no arguments. 
`public UserPage(){}`